# Writing if statement in one line

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, printing

While the following statement is correct:

```
print( "10 is greater than 5" ) if 10>5 else print( "nothing here " )
```

Removing the else cause errors `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`

```
print( "10 is greater than 5" ) if 10>5
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Because you're missing the parentheses around the first call to `print`.  Try: `print("10 is greater than 5") if 10>5 else print("nothing here ")`

Comment: It will work `print ("10 is greater than 5") if 10>5 else print( "nothing here " )
`

Comment: I was wondering how you could forget the parentheses for `if` statement, though you did it for `else` statement.

Comment: i updated the question, the missing () was a typo.

Comment: Nikolaos, minor note: you need an else, but it can just be `. . . else x=1` or such

Comment: Is it aboslutely necessary to use an else in my if? what if i don't need an else?

Comment: @ΝικόλαοςΒέργος Then you should use a proper `if` statement instead of the conditional operator.

Comment: @gibberish No, you cannot. The ternary operator in Python cannot be used with assignments. `. . . else None` can be used instead.

Comment: it just surpsise me that print("10 is greater than 5") if 10 > 5 else print("nothing here") works and if we ommit else it does not

Answer (score 6):

`print` is a function, and it takes a single value. In other words, you need a single call to `print`, and represent the value it takes as a onliner `if`:

```
print ("10 is greater than 5" if 10 > 5 else "nothing here")
```

Comment: This version works but it's not required. The OP's version is valid as well (with missing parentheses).

Comment: Only in python 2 though. The question asks about 3

Answer (score 4):

Alternately you could write

```
print("10 is greater than 5" if 10>5 else "nothing here ")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use parenthesis for the print statement

```
print("10 is greater than 5") if 10>5 else print("nothing here ")
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your python version, you are missing (or including) parenthesis on the call to print.

For Python 2.7.x, you can do:

```
print "10 is greater than 5" if 10 > 5 else "nothing here"
```

For Python 3.x you can do:

```
print("10 is greater than 5") if 10 > 5 else print("nothing here")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an if statement to be a one liner:

```
if 10>5: print( "10 is greater than 5" )
```

EDIT:

We can reverse the action and the condition by hacking the system as follows:

```
(lambda: None, lambda: print("10 is greater than 5"))[10>5]()
```

EDIT2:

A small explanation about the why.

.. if .. else was an invention by the Python people to introduce a ternary operator in the Python language. Traditional this is condition?action:action. However in the Python philosophy we want to make things explicit, therefore the wordy approach is used with ..if..else. What's more, this is an operator, so meant to be used in an assignment to combine multiple values to a value that can be assigned. Like in `a = b + c`, the `+` is an summation operator adding b and c, and assigning the result to c. In the same sense ..if..else are operators working on three different values and assign to something. That's why it is called a ternary operator. `+` is called a binary operator.

But instead of putting values to operate on, you can put functions between the operators, which are in turn executed when the Python interpreter tries to ask for them. (Just like you can do `a = sum(numbers) + 10`. There is a function (`sum`) at the place Python expects a value, so it executed the function `sum` to get that value. So, actually Python is only interested in getting the value of the print function (which is None) and to assign it to something, which it cannot. Printing was more a side effect.)

if ..: .. However is not an operator, but a control flow tool. This means that it can execute a *block* of code after the if statement. What's more I can put in this block of code statements, for example assignments. But off course this block could be a single function instead.

To give some examples:

```
x = 1 if y > 5 else x = 10
```

The above is not allowed, because Python expects to work on values and gets statements (assignments). Instead use:

```
x = 1 if y > 5 else 10
```

But using the control flow tool `if` we can provide statements:

```
if y > 5: x = 1
```

To go even further. Print in Python2 was a statement not a function.

So this will not even work in Python2, despite it looks like it is a function and is correct and working code in Python3:

```
print("this") if True else print("that") # does not work in Python2!
```

Comment: Thats what i want but in reversing order, by putting print() first then the if cause

Comment: Yeah, then go for the format: `do#1 if condition else do#2`

Comment: @ΝικόλαοςΒέργος Sure?

Comment: @khelwood Thank you. It was more a joke, but now the joke even works correctly. I would recommend OP to just use Python as it is meant to be used.

Comment: it just surpsise me that  `print("10 is greater than 5") if 10 > 5 else print("nothing here")` works and if we ommit `else` it does not.